# Best Way of Ensuring Safe Fetching From Data Dict

Tags: python

I've got a Python file in my project called `constants.py` which carries some dictionaries with a bunch of constants, for example links to images:

```
logos = {'team0': 'link0', 'team1': 'link1', 'dummy_team': 'link_dummy'}
```

When fetching a team's image link I want it to try to fetch said team's link, and if not possible return the dummy link.

When doing this is it common practice to use a try/except block like:

```
def fetch_team_logo(team: str) -> str:
    try:
        return constants.logos[team]
    except KeyError:
        return constants.logos['dummy_team']
```

Or with if/else like:

```
def fetch_team_logo(team: str) -> str:
    if team in constats.logos:
        return constants.logos[team]
    else:
        return constants.logos['dummy_team']
```

Comment: `constants.logos.get(team, constants.logos['dummy_team'])`?

Comment: As @AbdulNiyasPM write, neither - use the `get` method, which exists just for that. If OTOH there was no `get`, I would say try / except would be better than if/ else, because it works correctly even in a mulithreaded setup. "It is easier to ask for forgiveness than for permission."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the get function to get a value from a key with a default value that will get returned if nothing got found:

```py
logos = {'team0': 'link0', 'team1': 'link1', 'dummy_team': 'link_dummy'}
def fetch_team_logo(team: str) -> str:
    return logos.get(team, logos["dummy_team"])
```